# How to parse Spring Integration HTTP gateway response into a Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I've been trying to get a simple integration workflow for practice purposes. The thing is I just started working with Spring and I'm having a hard time understanding Integration and how it works.

Right now I've got a really simple backend app with Spring MVC that returns

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Series test","synopsis":"Testing reading items from JSON.","imageUrl":"http://some.where/images/some_image.png"},
{"id":2,"name":"Arrow","synopsis":"Some guy in a hood shooting arrows to some guys with superpowers.","imageUrl":"http://some.where/images/some_image.png"},
{"id":3,"name":"Primeval","synopsis":"Some guys with guns killing dinosaurs and lots of infidelity.","imageUrl":"http://some.where/images/some_image.png"},
{"id":4,"name":"Dr. Who","synopsis":"It's bigger on the inside.","imageUrl":"http://some.where/images/some_image.png"},
{"id":5,"name":"Fringe","synopsis":"Weird things happen.","imageUrl":"http://some.where/images/some_image.png"},
{"id":6,"name":"Monster Hunter Freedom Unite","synopsis":"Wait. This is a game.","imageUrl":"http://some.where/images/some_image.png"}
]
```

to `http://localhost:9000/api/series/findAll` and a runnable Spring project that, with Integration, attempts to recover that data and convert it to a `Series` (bean with the same properties as the JSON) array.

If I don't add a `reply-channel` to the `outbound-gateway` everything works just fine. But when I send it to another channel to parse it into a `Series` object I start getting "Dispatcher has no subscribers" on the new channel. It makes sense but it leaves me not knowing how to proceed now.

My project files, apart from Series, look like this right now:

**Startup.java**

```
package com.txus.integration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Startup {
    @Autowired
    RequestGateway requestGateway;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration-components.xml");

        RequestGateway requestGateway = context.getBean(RequestGateway.class);
        Future<String> promise = requestGateway.getSeries("");

        while (!promise.isDone()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        String response = promise.get();
        printReadable(response);

        context.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void printReadable(String string) {
        String separator = "= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =";
        System.out.println("\n" + separator + "\n" + string + "\n" + separator + "\n");
    }

    public static void printReadable(List<String> strings) {
        for (String string : strings) printReadable(string);
    }
}
```

---

**RequestGateway**

```
package com.txus.integration;


import com.txus.entities.Series;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public interface RequestGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel="responseChannel")
    Future<String> getSeries(String jsonString);

    @Gateway(requestChannel="responseChannel")
    Future<String> getSeries(Series series);
}
```

---

**integration-components.xml**

```
<beans:beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http      http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.txus"/>


    <!-- START: Spring Integration -->
    <!-- Integration: Channels -->

    <channel id="requestChannel"/>
    <channel id="responseChannel"/>

    <channel id="failedChannel"/>


    <!-- Integration: Loggers -->

    <logging-channel-adapter
            id="payloadLogger" level="DEBUG" expression="'### Message [' + headers.id + '] payload: ' + payload"/>
    <logging-channel-adapter
            id="headersLogger" level="DEBUG" expression="'### Message [' + headers.id + '] headers: ' + headers"/>


    <!-- Integration: Flow -->

    <gateway
            service-interface="com.txus.integration.RequestGateway"
            default-request-timeout="5000" async-executor="executor">

        <method name="getSeries" request-channel="inputChannel"/>
    </gateway>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="100"/>


    <payload-type-router input-channel="inputChannel" default-output-channel="failedChannel">
        <mapping type="java.lang.String" channel="requestChannel"/>
        <mapping type="com.txus.entities.Series" channel="objectToJSONChannel"/>
    </payload-type-router>


    <object-to-json-transformer
            id="objectToJsonTransformer" input-channel="objectToJSONChannel" output-channel="requestChannel"/>


    <http:outbound-gateway
            http-method="GET"
            expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
            url="http://localhost:9000/api/series/findAll"
            request-channel="requestChannel"
            reply-channel="jsonToSeries"
            reply-timeout="30000"/>


    <map-to-object-transformer
            input-channel="jsonToSeries" output-channel="responseChannel" type="com.txus.entities.Series"/>


    <!-- END: Spring Integration -->

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the last component where you configure `output-channel="responseChannel"`. There is just nothing which is subscribed to that channel.

I see your `@Gateway` config on the matter, but it is a bit wrong. XML configuration has a precedence over annotations there. Hence the `requestChannel` in the end is exactly `inputChannel`.

If you'd like to send the result of `<map-to-object-transformer>` to the `responseChannel` and accept it as a `return` from the `RequestGateway` invocation, you should specify that `responseChannel` as a `reply-channel` on the gateway configuration.

From other side you just don't need it there and the `TemporaryReplyChannel` comes to the rescue.

Please, refer for more information to the Spring Integration [Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway).

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood how the gateway worked and that's what kept me from going anywhere. I was indeed receiving inputChannel. Setting `reply-channel=responseChannel` inside the gateway's method after having properly parsed it (in the end I decided to parse it into an array instead of a list and had to do the proper changes) did the trick. Sorry I took so long to answer. I wanted to make sure everything worked before I did.